# Overlay for Electron when loading in MainWindow | BrowserWindow | BrowserView

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I'm developing a Client for an Complex website, thats why I want a loading animation to overlay while loading The external resource. I'm looking for a solution to overlay over my Window when loading my external Resource.

I don't really get why this is taking me so long, it seems to me like something a lot of people need. It almost seems like I'm missing something.

I tried with childs, but those open in separate windows. I tried with modals, but you know, modals are modals... Then I tried with BrowserViews which looked to me like the solution at first but why do I have to set bounds, why can't I set it to cover the full BrowserWindow automatically.